# Name/fragment link not working on dynamically built page

Tags: javascript, html, fragment-identifier

I'm building a page dynamically:

```
document.body.appendChild.....
```

and trying to build/link to sections with fragment identifies on the fly.

when I attach an anchor element with a fragment link (*after* creating/attaching the corresponding div: `yournamehere`):

```
<a href="#yournamehere">yournamehere</a>
```

The link does not work (scroll to the div named `yournamehere`). Why? Do fragment URLs not work when a page is built via JavaScript?

edit: 
pseudo-js:

```
var div = makeElement("<div name='yournamehere'></div>");
    document.body.appendChild(div);

var a = makeElement('<a href="#yournamehere">yournamehere</a>')
    document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: you are using `name`, to select and element using `#` you should use `id`

Comment: @CalvinNunes unfortunately that does not work either.

Comment: @CalvinNunes oops! nvm, you're 100% right, ID works. I could have sworn the name attribute was what corresponds to fragment urls. thanks! feel free to post so I give you internet points :P

Comment: name works that way in HTML4 but not HTML5